# Filtering for criteria in Pandas Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a table I have parsed from a URL:

```
dfs = pd.read_html('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/', header = 0)
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

I have isolated a particular column called `Internet Points`:

```
df1 = df['Internet Points']
```

I'd like to filter search this column for `Internet Points > 1000`. I've tried:

```
if df1 > 10000:
print(df1)
```

However, I get an error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use `a.empty`, `a.bool()`, `a.item()`, `a.any()` or `a.all()`.

Comment: Try `df1[df1>10000]` a simple boolean indexing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: [Boolean Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this

```
for _, val in df1.iteritems():
    if val > 1000:
        print(val)
```

Or you can also do it by using the method `map`

```
df1.map(lambda x: x if x > 1000 else None)
```

After you have filtered out the column using `df1 = df['Internet Points']`, the variable `df1` becomes a `pandas.core.series.Series` type which is basically a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html). If you filter it using `df1 > 10000`, what you will get is just another [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) with boolean values, so you can also do something like below:

```
print(df1[df1>10000])
```

If you want to output an array, you can also use

```
print(df1[df1>10000].values)
```